# MSBuild - Override MinimalRebuild (/Gm) to false

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

After some research, to get VisualStudio to build a project's object files in parallel, one must ensure that project properties `MinimalRebuild` is off and `MultiProcessorCompilation` is on. I can configure this in the project file, but is there a way to override these project settings on the command line using `msbuild`?

In other words, using msbuild from the command line, how would I override `MinimalRebuild` (`/Gm-`) to be false and `MultiProcessorCompilation` (`/MP`) to be true? The following doesn't seem to work

`msbuild /m:7 /p:CL_MPCount=7 /p:MinimalRebuild=false /p:MultiProcessorCompilation=true`

As an aside, is `/p:CL_MPCOUNT` redundant with the `MultiProcessorCompilation` property? Overall, I'm having trouble finding documentation on what fits the `/p` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In other words, using msbuild from the command line, how would I
>   override MinimalRebuild (/Gm-) to be false and
>   MultiProcessorCompilation (/MP) to be true?

`CL_MPCount` can be overrided by `/p:xxx=xxx` but `MultiProcessorCompilation` and `MinimalRebuild` are not. Just to be clear, It can only be overridden by `/p:xxx=xxx`(**p means property**) if it is a property of MSBuild. And the Property usually can be called by `$`. So I do some tests:

**Edit**

**Test**

**1）CL_MPCount**

This value means Maximum Number of concurrent C++ compilations in VS IDE.You can refer to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/checkedc-clang/wiki/Parallel-builds-of-clang-on-Windows#visual-studio-ide).

So I have assigned a value by VS IDE by(Debug->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Project Solutions and set the `Maximum Number of concurrent C++ compilations` to 2.)

write a custom target like

```
<Target Name ="Test" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="CL_MPCount is= $(CL_MPCount)">
    </Message>
  </Target>
```

Then Build and it shows；
[image]

From this we can see that this is a property that belongs to MSBuild.

**2）MinimalRebuild**

Usually, it means [/GM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gm-enable-minimal-rebuild?view=vs-2019) and it usually set in the Properties in a c++ project. l have set it to `True` by (Right-click on the project-->Properties-->C/C++-->Code Generation-->set `Enable Minimal Rebuild` to `True`).

Custom target like

```
<Target Name ="Test" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="MinimalRebuild is= $(MinimalRebuild)">
        </Message>
      </Target>
```

The result is like

[image]

From it, the value which set in the VS IDE cannot be available by `$(MinimalRebuild)` which means it is not a property of MSBuild.

**3) MultiProcessorCompilation**

It also means [/MP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/mp-build-with-multiple-processes?view=vs-2019#visual-studio-project-settings) and from the document we will find that it is an option of the the compiler not a property of MSBuild. Besides, l did the same as the `MinimalRebuild` and it is not being output. So it is also not a property of MSBuild.

**In addition**, l thought `MinimalRebuild` and `MultiProcessorCompilation` are the options of MSBuild before. So I type `MSBuild -help` in Command Line and found that it did not list these parameters at all. So I think these two parameters have nothing to do with MSBuild at all, but are just some of the compiler's options.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: It is interesting though that you can override some things, for example `/p:CL_MPCOUNT` will pass an additional argument to `cl`. I couldn't even find where `CL_MPCOUNT` was documented. Is there such a place that shows these special properties?

Comment: Interesting. I will look into clang on Windows. It autogenerates msbuild files. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to override both properties at *User level*. Anyway you may find them helpful (for example for Build host where incremental build is not meaningful at all).

Create these two properties files:

- `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props`
- `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props`

with following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <MinimalRebuild>false</MinimalRebuild>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>true</MultiProcessorCompilation>
      <ProcessorNumber>2</ProcessorNumber>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

Feel free to customize `ProcessorNumber` to suit your hardware.

Now MSBUild will use above values for *all projects*.